# Added too much cayenne to my spice mix, how to fix it?

Tags: spices, chili-peppers

Added too much cayenne powder to my spice mix, now it’s too hot. What can I do to fix it and tone down the heat?

The mix contains sugar, garlic powder, onion powder, kosher salt, pepper, allspice & cayenne (of which I used twice as much as required).

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure: You mean “cayenne” (as in the spice), not “cyan” (as in the blue-green color), right? I edited the post for now, in the unlikely case that I made a mistake, feel free to [edit] again.

Comment: Tweezers and a magnifying glass

Answer (score 8):

The best thing to do is add enough of the others to make it up to double quantity, then use half and save the other half for another time.

Comment: … or see if you like it hot ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin that's the other option, but it did sound like too much for their tastes.

Answer (score 0):

When I overdo the “ heat” I add a bit of sweetener as I find it makes your saliva glands more active and that seems to make the  heat a little less intense ..I use maple syrup for thee sweetener in my hot sauce.

Comment: Welcome! Let me give you some advice for new users: this is not a forum, where there are ongoing threads of discussions, but one specific question at the top and only specific and individual answers below. In other words, each answer should be written as standalone post, not a commentary on another answer. I would very much encourage you to read [answer] and, if you see fit, [edit] your posts. It seems you have a lot of experience which would be valuable and appreciated, let us help you get started with the formal rules.

Comment: Thanks , my writing has degenerated over time  to bullet points . I will take your comments under consideration.